# Failed to determine a suitable driver class: Вылетает при попытке подключения postgresql в java проект

Tags: java

[image: application.properties]

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.2.RELEASE
         
    
    com.example
    serving-web-content
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    serving-web-content
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: добавьте код, в которым вызываете БД.
К базе пробовали подключиться через какие-либо программы по тем настройкам, что указали?

Comment: Прошу прощения, изучаю технологию по видео уроку https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyFLX3q3poY&t=640s  Делал все так.

Comment: Ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/drucoder/sweater/tree/JPA_Postgres

Comment: У вас установлена база данных Postgresql? Там у пользователя `postgres` пароль который указали в файле `application.properties`?
Запускали в базе данных `sweater` скрипты из папочки 
`sweater\src\main\resources\db\migration`?

Comment: Пробовали без этой строки `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver`?